# Creating DXF from WFS Saves Slowly

Tags: qgis-3, wfs, dxf

I'm currently required to periodically pull cadastral lines from a WFS server and my current methodology is resulting in slow saves.

I first query a very large layer within the WFS with a known primary key to isolate 1 shape. I then adjust my map extent to cover the area I require and then Add the layer again except this time with no query and just the *"Only request features overlapping the view extent"* button checked.

This then shows me all the shapes within my view and I'm happy with that, the problem arises when I make a selection of say 20-50 polygons, right click the layer and then go export -> *"Save selected features as.."*

I choose DXF and then it hangs on 99%, the save does eventually work but it takes upwards of 15minutes and some random timeout errors. Once this save is done I can save another separate selection within the same screen instantly any ideas?

Also I would prefer lines instead of polygons so I usually do "polygons to lines" which also works but suffers the same 15 minute delay.

[image: This is an example of the data I need]

This is an example of the data and need in isolation instead of my entire state which will crash QGIS.

[image]
And this is where I'm trying to limit the geometry I get to my current map but with no success.

Comment: why do you not just save the polygon you first select?

Comment: I need 20-50 polygons usually I just pull that 1 to get in the right area

Comment: most likely issue is that the WFS is having to go through the whole file to find the ones you selected - I'm not sure if QGIS passes the filter to the remote server, you'd need to check the network requests to see

Comment: I tried saving just the first polygon and it was instant, you may be right so it's something to do with when I get objects overlapping view extent.

Is there a way to query my current map extents instead? I'm thinking that might be the solution.